# Parse Cloud Code User Validation

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I want to validate an iOS user calling a Cloud Code function.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sayMyName", function(request, response) {
  var user = request.user; 
  console.log(user);
  response.success("Your name is: " + user.get("name"));
)};
```

However this always brings up `undefined`. There doesn't seem to be any documentation about this, and it is Parse specific, so my hands are kind of tied.

Within Cloud Code, how do I determine which user is calling the function?

Comment: How and where do you call your Cloud function ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and make sure user has name as key.

Comment: The problem was the `"name"` key. `request.user` is the right accessor. If you remove the first 4 lines I'll accept your answer

Comment: Unfortunately this severe edit means the answer now shows up as a Low Quality Post.  I suggest you add some context explaining why this solves the problem.  Help others to understand.

Comment: @virendrao @APC is right. You should edit your answer to `The user in a Parse request object does not get initialized with a 'name' parameter.`